# Does Classic ASP pages called with Querystring parameters are cached by the HTTP-level Kernel cache?

Tags: cache, iis, iis7

Our company have a website made in Classic ASP, which **most of them are static pages**.
We have enabled Kernal cache for 30 seconds in our *web.config* file in order to speed-up the displaying of all our webpages :

```
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxCacheSize="512" maxResponseSize="524288">
    <profiles>
        <add extension="*" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" varyByQueryString="*" varyByHeaders="accept-encoding, accept-language" location="Server" duration="00:00:30"/>
    </profiles>
</caching>
```

We have **one dynamic page** displaying customer information :
This page display information based on the **Request.Querystring("userId")** parameter :

EXAMPLE. `https://website.com/user.asp?userId=12345`

Our question is the following : Do you confirm me the fact that this dynamic page **will never be cached for other users**, as it always have a different URL (based on the *userId* parameter) ?

We need to be sure that **userId=12345** will NEVER see cached information for **userID=56789**, even if they access the "user.asp" page in the same cache timeframe (30 seconds) ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kernel Cache in IIS needs several conditions to be met by the requested resource in order to be cached. One of those conditions is that **it should not contain any query string**. You can check it in Microsoft's Knowledge Base here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/817445/instances-in-which-http-sys-does-not-cache-content

> if one or more of the following conditions are true, HTTP.sys does not cache the request response:
>
> ....
>
> - The request contains a query string.

It makes total sense, and that's exactly the use case that you need.

HTH

Comment: BTW, you can check the caching status of any request, even in kernel mode, by using IIS FREB (Failed Request Event Buffering). If you check the report for your request you can find the different stages of caching and can check if it's being used or not.